# how to cancel page transition in jqtouch

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I am building a simple app in jqTouch that has a wizard style set up, a page of inputs, a second page of inputs and then a results page.

I want to write some validation for the form and prevent the user going to the next page if they dont fill the form out correctly.

Here is the test method I have written:

```
      $('#page1').bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e, data) {
          if(data.direction === 'out') {
              if($("#testinput").val() == "") {
                  $("#validation").text("validation error");
                  e.stopPropagation();
                  return false;
              }
          }
      });
```

The event is run by jquery `trigger()` which says I can stop it using `e.stopPropagation();` or `return false;`.

I have tried both individually. The validation error message appears but the page still passes to the next.

I have [checked the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/CallbackEvents) but it is pretty sparse and I couldn't find any code examples that show how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the function to the click & touchstart so that the propogation stops before the page animation starts.

```
$('#page1').bind('click touchstart touchend', function(e) {
      if($("#testinput").val() == "") {
          $("#validation").text("validation error");
          e.stopPropagation();
          return false;
      } 
  });
```